# hidding 2 of the 3 div having the same class with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html strucutre :

```
         <p><input id="hide" type="radio" ....
         <p><input id="open" type="radio" ....
<div class="item-address">...</dv>   
<div class="item-address">...</dv>
<div class="item-address">...</dv>
          .....
```

I want to hide all divs but not the first one !!

Can you help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.item-address:not(:first)').hide();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tVxrM/

Comment: @Rastaking Great. Please mark as `best answer` for future users.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".item-address:not(`:first`)").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".item-address:not(:first)").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by simple adding a extra css class in the div except the first one.

```
<div>
        <div class="item-address">
            First Div</div>
        <div class="item-address hideItem">
            Second Div </div>
        <div class="item-address hideItem">
            Third Div</div>
    </div>
```

here **hideItem** is a css class and no need to define any property for this class.

Use this jQuery syntax to active the goal.

```
 $(".hideItem").hide();
```